# Script works well in python console but crashes when "Run Script" in text editor?

Tags: python, scripting

I have a python script. It works well when I run the code in python console but if I open the script file in text editor and click "Run Script", blender crashed.

Does anyone know what might causes the difference?

Here is the script:

```
import bpy 
from bpy import data as D 
from bpy import context as C 
from mathutils import * 
from math import * 
import blensor 
bpy.context.scene.objects.active=bpy.data.objects['Camera']
blensor.tof.scan_advanced( max_distance = 20.0)
```

Comment: Yan, pasting the script in your question might give some clues.

Comment: It could be a number of things, the easiest way to find out is to [toggle system console](http://puu.sh/k5tti.png) found in the window menu if you are on Windows. This will open a second window which will be a text console. Any errors when running the script will be reported here so you can find the cause. If you can't solve the issue you will have to post the actual script here before anyone can help.

Comment: I am using the python script to execute blensor add on.
Here is the script:


import bpy
from bpy import data as D
from bpy import context as C
from mathutils import *
from math import *

import blensor

bpy.context.scene.objects.active=bpy.data.objects['Camera']

blensor.tof.scan_advanced( max_distance = 20.0)

Comment: Thank you! I have toggled the system console. When blender crashed, system console also disappeared. When I run the script in commond line by " blender myscene.blend --background --python myscript.py". The crash message it gives indicates some parameter is not set. For this parameter, it has a default value. And everything works well in python console. So it confuses me.

Comment: Here are the information when I run the script using blender in cmd.exe: |
Preparing Scene data
|Creating Shadowbuffers
| Raytree.. preparing
Raytree.. building
Raytree finished
Creating Environment maps
Fra:1 Mem:5.33M (0.00M, Peak 5.35M) | Caching Point Densities
Fra:1 Mem:5.33M (0.00M, Peak 5.35M) | Loading voxel datasets
Fra:1 Mem:5.33M (0.00M, Peak 5.35M) | SSS preprocessing
Fra:1 Mem:5.33M (0.00M, Peak 5.35M) | Volume preprocessing
Fra:1 Mem:5.33M (0.00M, Peak 5.35M) Sce: Scene Ve:42 Fa:40 La:1
The refractive index of the world is: 1.000000
Writing: C:\blender.crash.txt

Comment: @Yan, edit the original question to post the script.  It needs to be indented for it to be formatted as script.  This can be done in blender script window by selecting all and hitting the tab key before copying and pasting here.  Shift tab un-indents.

Comment: @leon-stafford not sure what that script is - those import lines contain some horrible frightening shivering things! Beyond that, since we do not know what does the blensor code, it's very hard to answer…

Comment: @mont29, thanks, I've not touched Python for a while and trimmed comments in the wrong places! [Blensor project](https://github.com/mgschwan/blensor)